# classify labels to -1 or 1

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor with values between -1 and 1 . How can I get a new tensor such that where were negative values now there will be one and where were positive numbers now there will be 1? (efficiently)

Namely,

```
tensor1 = [-0.1, 0.5, 0.08]
new_tensor = [-1, 1, 1]
```

**and zero will be -1 or 1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With numpy it is trivial:

```
import numpy as np
tensor1 = [-0.1, 0.5, 0.08]
new_tensor = np.sign(tensor1)
new_tensor[new_tensor==0] = 1
```

Comment: but in this case zero will be zero. How can I turn it to 1 or to -1?

Comment: What do you want zero to be?

Comment: In case, add a line
`new_tensor[new_tensor==0] = 1 # or -1`

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for this task following way

```
import numpy as np
tensor1 = np.array([-0.1, 0.5, 0.08])
new_tensor = np.where(tensor1<0,-1,1)
print(new_tensor)
```

output

```
[-1  1  1]
```

Note this will asign `1` to `0` if you wish to assign `-1` to `0` then alter condition to `tensor1<=0`